# Overloading only one specific attribute of __init__

Tags: python, inheritance, overloading, init

I have a question regarding inheritance / overloading. To understand my problem, I think it is best to first show a piece of code:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 10
        self.var2 = 20
        self.var3 = 30

class B(A):
    def __init__(self): #Bad, because I am probably overloading the whole "constructor"
        self.var2 = 15
```

Class B inherits from class A. Now to my question, is there a way to only overload the value of attribute self.var2 in class B, while keeping self.var1 and self.var3 as they are?

Comment: Just use `super` first

Comment: just call init of the base class first. Either using super() or directly as A.__init__. Most probably a duplicate.

Comment: As dull as it may seem, it is useful to learn the terminology: this is called overriding, not overloading. Overloading is something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have any weirdness in `A`, like read-only properties, you can simply allow `A.__init__` to do its job, and then change the one value you want to in `B.__init__`:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.var2 = 15
```

But this raises some possible issues with the design. If `A` is intended to be extensible, it might be worth considering using default values for the parameters instead of hard coding them into the constructor:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, var1=10, var2=20, var3=30):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        self.var3 = var3
```

Now child classes can call their `super` initializer and override only the values they need:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(var2=15)
```

or better yet

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, var2=15):
        super().__init__(var2=var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are conceptually misunderstanding the OOPs paradigm. First of all the initializer is only meant to initialize the object of the class, however in your code `__init__` has hard codes values for attributes, so every object of the class will have the same value for these attributes.

If this is what you want then make these as class variables or just make attribute `b` as a class attribute.

Secondly in your class `B`, though you are inheriting from class `A` the initializer is not being overloaded, because you are not explicitly calling `__init__` of `super` class. So either use `super().__init__()` in class B or simply just remove it, then it will automatically call `__init__` of the super class.

Hope it makes things more clear.